# How can I extract text under html div id tag in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I was wondering how I would be able to extract the text from this tag from this website: https://ru.thefreedictionary.com/%d1%88%d1%87%d0%be

```
<div id="MainTxt">


            Слово в словаре не найдено.
 <div id="didYouMean"></div>Быть может, вы искали:
<div style="margin:6px 0 3px 0">
```

The code I'm using gets everything under the id tag, but I'm looking only to get the text 'Слово в словаре не найдено.'

```
soup.findAll("div", attrs = {"id": ["MainTxt"]})
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please recheck your html snippet. You have a couple of unclosed tags and that would make it difficult to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to combine `findAll()` with `id` attribute because there can only be **one** element with that `id` in that html so `findAll()` will always return list of one element. Here is how you could solve your problem.

```
match = soup.find('div', {'id': 'MainTxt'})
text = match.text.rstrip().lstrip().split('\n')
```

`rstrip()` and `lstrip()` are for removing trailing spaces in front and in the back of the string. Now `text` is a list of elements: `['Слово в словаре не найдено.\r', ' Быть может, вы искали:\r', '', ...]`. To get your target string is easy.

```
target_string = text[0].replace('\r', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you're having is that there is no `</div>` on the html page directly after 'Слово в словаре не найдено.'

That means that "MainTxt" includes everything until the next `</div>` that isn't opened. You can think of these much like parentheses or curly brackets.

So this is similar to . . .

```
Maintxt{
Слово в словаре не найдено.
didYouMean{}Быть может, вы искали:
```

You could try taking all of Maintxt, like in your code, and then removing all additional divs, but unfortunately this may not be as simple as a one-liner, since the html you're working with doesn't wrap Слово в словаре не найдено. in its own div